# Rally SDK 2 Grid with Timebox Filtering

Tags: javascript, rally

Using the example from https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/timebox_filtering for a timebox required app, how do I convert the cardBoard view into a grid?

This is the base code:

```
Ext.define('Rally.guide.ReleaseFilteredBoard', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    scopeType: 'release',

    onScopeChange: function(scope) {
        if(!this.board) {
             this.board = this.add({
                xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                storeConfig: {
                    filters: [scope.getQueryFilter()]
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.board.refresh({
                storeConfig: {
                    filters: [scope.getQueryFilter()]
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It seems that I can simply change the xtype to 'rallygrid' and based on docs it should work but it seems to need a model defined as well - how do I get the model details out of the timebox scope to feed into the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to check out the example code for [Rally.ui.grid.Grid](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/example/Grid).

Here's a quick sample of how one might apply the Timebox filter to a grid:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    grid: null,

    launch: function() {

        var filters = [];
        var timeboxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope();

        if(timeboxScope) {
            filters.push(timeboxScope.getQueryFilter());
        }

        this.getFilteredStoryModel(filters);            
    },

    onTimeboxScopeChange: function(newTimeboxScope) {               
        var newFilters = [];
        var updatedTimeboxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope();
        if (this.grid) {
            this.grid.destroy();
        }                   
        if (updatedTimeboxScope) {
            newFilters.push(newTimeboxScope.getQueryFilter());
        }
        this.getFilteredStoryModel(newFilters);
    },

    getFilteredStoryModel: function(queryFilters) {
        Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'UserStory',
            success: function(model) {
                this.grid = this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    model: model,
                    columnCfgs: [
                        'FormattedID',
                        'Name',
                        'Owner',
                        'Iteration'
                    ],
                    storeConfig: {
                        filters: queryFilters
                    }
                });
            },
            scope: this
        });                 
    }
});
```

To show the timebox filter, choose the type of filter you desire when first setting up your Custom Page in Rally. The "onTimeboxScopeChange" callback responds to events triggered by the timebox selector setup and configured on the Custom Page container itself. No code is needed to setup the timebox selector, rather you do it via the Rally UI when creating a new Custom Page:

[image: New Custom Page]

Select the type of filter (Release or Iteration):

[image: Select Filter Type]

(1) Note that the filter shows on the "My New Custom Page" Container. (2) Any app that you add to "My New Custom Page" will then have the timebox filter available/applied:

[image: Custom Page with Timebox Filter]

Add Custom HTML App:

[image: Add Custom HTML]

Paste in Code and Save:

[image: Paste In HTML/Javascript Code]

Iteration-filtered Grid:

[image: Iteration-filtered Grid]

Alternatively, if you don't want a timebox filter that applies to an entire Custom Page container, you can elect to use [Rally.ui.combobox.ReleaseComboBox](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.ReleaseComboBox) or [Rally.ui.combobox.IterationComboBox](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.IterationComboBox)

In your App code itself, and manage the filtering via callbacks from either of these components. This filtering would be totally "within-app" and wouldn't rely on the Custom Page-wide timebox component.

Comment: Great example, thanks - much clearer to me now, how do I get the filter to display under this approach?